# How to get the id or class an HTML element clicked?using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to get the id or class of any element that is clicked using Jquery?I don't know the ID of the element i want asynchronouly clicked element ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click',function() {
 var classes = $(this).attr('class');
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

This is for any click done on the page, for an specific element:

```
 $("#elem_id").on('click',function(){
     var classes = $(this).attr('class');
     var id = $(this).attr('id');});
```

Comment: Thanks,I don't know the id of element which is clicked want asnchronouly clicked element id.

Comment: The first piece of code registers all clicks made, so on each click vars "classes" and "id" will be assigned with the classes and id of the element clicked

Comment: thnx understood properly.

Answer (score 0):

> In Html
>
> You can do various logic on its click event as

```
 $('#idget').click(function(){
     ....//logic
    });
```

> Or

```
  $('.customclass').click(function(){
      ....//logic
    });
```